# issue with rpyc marshalling of objects

Tags: psutil, rpyc

I am using rpyc (v 3.3.0) to get the list of processes running on a remote server using psutil module. My code is as below.

```
 server='hkl20056309'
 rpcClient = rpyc.classic.connect(server)
 rpsutil = rpcClient.modules.psutil
 procs = rpsutil.get_process_list()
```

I am getting the list of procs correctly but some of the processes attributes are not set correctly. for example:

```
>>> procs[166]._name
'mingetty'
>>> procs[140]._name
>>> procs[141]._name
>>> procs[142]._name
>>> procs[142]
<psutil.Process(pid=1828, name='gatengine') at 17483536>
>>> procs[142]._name
'gatengine'
>>>
```

If you see `procs[142]._name`  is not printed (value is `None`) until I access the object. If I print all the processes, I see the name as None for 143rd process object in the list. But after I access the object, suddenly I can see the correct value for the name.

Any suggestions on how I can resolve this issue?

Comment: unfortunately I have to print the `procs` object to make sure all it's content are updated. Is this a known issue?

Answer (score 1):

Never seen such an issue with RPyC. It's probably something to do with that Process. If you call str(proc) and then proc._name, instead of printing, does it help? Also, it seems like you're trying to use a private member (_name)... Perhaps that's the issue? Isn't there some public property you can use?